# how to access class's function's variable in another class in different file in python

Tags: python, json, oop

main class:(file name:main.py)

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json, requests
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
 def do_POST(self):
   content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
   post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
   dict = json.loads(post_data)
```

Another class in different file:(filename:sub.py)

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json, requests
import main

class myimprsn():
    myImpression = dict.get('imp')
```

I want to use dict variable from main file into sub file.can anybody help me how to do that?I am new to oop and python so please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? How is `myimprsn` used?

Comment: Just a little thing don't call dictionary `dict` use some other name...

Answer (score 0):

You can make `dict` global (and rename it so it doesn't clash with a builtin):

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json, requests

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        global data_dict
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        data_dict = json.loads(post_data)
```

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json, requests
import main

class myimprsn():
    myImpression = main.data_dict.get('imp')
```

However, this still won't help, as `main.data_dict` is read on startup, but only written after the first POST request.